# validating uniqueness of has_many association with a string "checksum"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I had an idea to validate the uniqueness of a has_many association: what if we generate a string based on the ids of the associated records?

For example:

```
class Exam
  has_many :problems   #problems are unique and can be in multiple exams

  validate :checksum, uniqueness: true   #string

  before_validate :check
  def check
    checksum = problems.map {|p| p.id}.join
  end
end
```

The edge case we want to solve is:
Given distinct problems `3x4`, `sqrt(4)`, `5+5`, etc.., we don't want all of them to be in more than one exam.

Does anyone have thoughts on this approach? Is there a better way to validate uniqueness of has_many?

(P.S. I'm not sure if "checksum" is the right term.)

Comment: Could you provide more information as to the context of this? Why would you need the has_many association to be unique? I'd imagine that if it is a `has_many` (and not a has_and_belongs_to_many) that no two exams will have the same `problems`.

Comment: @Olives You're right: to clarify, the problems are unique and can be in multiple exams. For example, the problem `sqrt(4) = ` is unique and can be used in multiple exams.

Answer (score 0):

Base on the following:

1. You have an `Exam` model and a `Problem` model
2. Each `Exam` `has_many` `Problem`s
3. Each problem must be unique per `Exam`

I think it makes more sense to place a `uniqueness` validation on an attribute of `Problem` but scope the validation to its `Exam` so that that multiple `Exams` can have the same `Problem`s but each `Exam` has a unique set of `Problem`s.

So for example if there was an attribute named `value`, we place the uniqueness validation on it and scope it to `exam_id`.

```
class Exam < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :problems
end

class Problem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :exam

  validates :value, :uniqueness => { :scope => :exam_id }
end
```

Comment: I like this approach, but it cannot validate the case of two exams having the same problems `1+2=` `2+2=` etc.